# compute the commutant of a compact self-adjoint operator

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $T$ is a compact self-adjoint operator on $H$, then $T=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_i P_i$, where each $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, $P_i$ is a projection from $H$ onto $ker(T-\lambda_i)$.

I want to calculate the commutant of $T$. Does the following relation hold?
$T'=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(\lambda_i P_i)'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the non-zero eigenvalues of $T$, let us make sure to include $\lambda_0=0$, and let $P_0$ be the orthonormal projection onto
the null space of $T$.  Then clearly
$$
  T = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_i P_i = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\lambda_i P_i,
  $$
and also
$$
  H = \bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty}P_i(H).
  $$

Notice that an operator $S$ commutes with $T$ iff $S$ commutes with every $P_i$:  the "if" part is obvious because
$T=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_i P_i$, and the  "only if" follows from the fact that each $P_i$ may be writen as a limit
of polynomials applied to $T$ by the functional calculus  (provided the $\lambda _i$'s are distinct).

Thus the commutant of $T$ coincides with the set of all operators leaving each $P_i(H)$ invariant.   Viewing these as
block-diagonal operators we then have
$$
  \{T\} ' = \bigoplus_i P_iB(H)P_i.
  $$

Comment: Why each $P_i$ is a limit of polynomials of $T$? $T^2=T$, so for each $n, T^n=T$.

Comment: If $f:\sigma (T)\to \mathbb C$ is the characteristic function of the singleton $\{\lambda _i\}$, then $P_i$ coincides with $f(T)$
(functional calculus).  By Stone-Weierstass you may approximate $f$ uniformly on $\sigma (T)$ by a sequence $\{p_n\}_n$ of  polynomials, so
  $$
  P_i = f(T) = \lim_np_n(T).
  $$

Comment: I have another question : the commutant of T coincides with the set of all operators leaving each $P_i(H)$, how to identify them as block diagonal matrix?

Comment: If a  Hilbert space $H$ is split as $H=\bigoplus_{n\in {\mathbb N}}H_n$,  then every bounded operator $T$ on $H$ gives rise to a
matrix $(T_{i, j})_{i, j}$, where each $T_{i,j}$ is the  operator from $H_j$ to $H_i$ defined by
  $$
  T_{i, j}= P_iT|_{H_j},
  $$
  and $P_i$ is the projection onto $H_i$.  If another operator $S$ has  matrix $(S_{i, j})_{i, j}$,
then the matrix of $ST$ may be nicely identified with the product of the corresponding matrices.  Now, if $T$ leaves
every $H_i$ invariant, then    $T_{i, j}=0$, for $i\neq j$, so its matrix is diagonal.

Comment: Very clear,!  Thanks so much!

Comment: In conway's book, if $N$ is a normal operator, we have $\chi_{\Sigma}(N)=E(\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is a Borel subset of $\sigma(N)$,  how to dedece that $P_i=E(\lambda_i)$?

Comment: Maybe we should take a more pedestrian approach.  Let me know if you can prove the following, without using any functional calculus or anything fancy:
  (1) If $f$ is a polynomial then $f(T)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(\lambda _i)P_i$.
  (2) If $\{a_i\}_i$ and $\{b_i\}_i$ are bounded sequences of scalars then
  $$
  \left\|\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_iP_i - \sum_{i=0}^\infty b_iP_i\right\| \leq \sup_i|a_i-b_i|.
  $$
  (3) If $\{f_n\}_n$ is a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to the characteristic function of some $\{\lambda _{i_0}\}$ on $\sigma (T)$, then $f_n(T)$ converges to $P_{i_0}$.

Comment: May I ask you this question ?https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375296/jordan-homomorphism-between-von-neumann-algebras